# Using jackson with spring mvc 2.5

Tags: ajax, json, spring-mvc, jackson

sorry for general question, but I can't google anything on that, we use spring mvc 2.5 in our project, so there is no @ResponseBody annotation, how can I make something like [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/) without it?

Answer (score 1):

You could just return it as a string built with the Jackson object mapper:

```
public String getCustomDetails(@PathVariable String variable1) {

    CustomDetails details = new CustomDetails(variable1);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String result = null;   

    result = mapper.writeValueAsString(details);

    return result;
}
```

That should work.  Might have to surround the call to writeValueAsString in a try-catch.

Edit:  I should clarify that "CustomDetails" and "variable1" are just example values... they could be anything.

Comment: Thank you, I ll try that. And what if i need to return complex object, for example list of maps of maps? Or something in this way, will it work?

Comment: My immediate thought is that, yes, it would work.  But I have not tried it, so I can't confirm that it definitely does.  Good luck.